# A surprisingly complex ActiveRecord relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `User` model. A user has many `EmailAddresses`, and they choose one of these as their `primary_email_address`, which is the one I send out emails to. A user must always have at least one email address, and must have a primary email address set. The primary email address may be destroyed, but a new primary email address must then be assigned to the user.

This has proven to be a surprisingly tough situation to deal with, and every solution I have tried has some unsatisfactory elements. It seems like a very common class of problem (A has many B, and one of their Bs are special) so I'd love to know how to solve it cleanly.

#### Solution 1 - boolean column on EmailAddress saying whether it is primary or not

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :email_addresses, inverse_of: :user

  validates :has_exactly_one_primary_email_address

  def primary_email_address
    email_addresses.where(is_primary:true).first
  end

  def has_exactly_one_primary_email_address
    # ...
  end
end

class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :email_addresses

  before_destroy :check_not_users_only_email_address
  after_destroy :reassign_user_primary_email_address_if_necessary

  # the logic for both these methods should live on the user but you get the idea
  def reassign_user_primary_email_address_if_necessary
    # ...
  end

  def check_not_users_only_email_address
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is conceptually awkward because it is so important that a user has exactly one primary email address, and having to validate this across multiple email address records seems bad. And whilst I know that ActiveRecord transactions should mean that a user doesn't get stuck without a primary email address, it seems like a recipe for disaster. The primary email address is fundamentally something that belongs to the user, and putting this logic onto the EmailAddress model is unideal.

#### Solution 2 - `primary_email_adress_id` column on User in addition to `user_id` column on EmailAddress

Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :email_addresses, inverse_of: :user
  belongs_to :primary_email_address

  validates_presence_of :primary_email_address
end

class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :email_addresses

  before_destroy :check_not_users_only_email_address
  after_destroy :reassign_user_primary_email_address_if_necessary

  # the logic for both these methods should live on the user but you get the idea
  def reassign_user_primary_email_address_if_necessary
    # ...
  end

  def check_not_users_only_email_address
    # ...
  end
end
```

This is better, as the validation of a user having exactly 1 primary email address is much easier and much more tightly coupled to the User model. However, there are now annoying problems around inverses. `user.primary_email_address` doesn't refer to the same instance as the same record in the `user.email_addresses` array, and a lot of reloading is required to make sure your in memory instances have the right data.

```
> u = User.last
> u.email_addresses.map(&:email)
=> ["monkey@hotmail.com", "gorilla@gmail.com"]
> u.primary_email_address.destroy
=> true
> u.email_addresses.map(&:email)
=> ["monkey@hotmail.com", "gorilla@gmail.com"]
> u.reload
> u.email_addresses.map(&:email)
=> ["monkey@hotmail.com"]
```

This causes a lot of problems in `after_destroy` hooks and other situations. This seems to be causes by the slightly awkward `belongs_to :primary_email_address` line in the User model. It's a bit weird for EmailAddresses and Users to be related by these two different ActiveRecord relations (`has_many :email_addresses/belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :primary_email_address`).

2 solutions that both technically work (we are currently using the second one), but both with unintuitive and time-consuming flaws. I'd love to hear some good ideas of how to solve this properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the first approach, albeit slightly differently.  There isn't really any way to avoid setting trigger callbacks on the email address since that is where the modifications are taking place.  However, you don't need to make it as complex as you were.

Since the checks need to be made on the entire collection of EmailAddresses for the User, the database content should be used to make the determination of whether the state is valid or not - using `after_save` and `after_destroy` are an easy way to do this:

```
class EmailAdress < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of :email_addresses

  scope :primary, where(:primary => true)

  after_save :ensure_single_primary_email
  after_destroy :ensure_primary_email_exists

  def ensure_single_primary_email
    user.verify_primary_email(self) if new_record? || primary_changed?
  end

  def ensure_primary_email_exists
    user.ensure_primary_email
  end
end

class User < AR::Base
  has_many :email_addresses, :inverse_of => :user, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :primary_email_address

  validates_presence_of :primary_email_address

  def primary_email_address
    if association(:email_addresses).loaded? 
      email_addresses.detect(&:primary?)
    else
      email_addresses.primary.first
    end
  end

  def primary_email_address=(email)
    email.primary = true
    email_addresses << email
  end

  def verify_primary_email(email)
    if email.primary? && email_addresses.primary.count > 1
      raise "Only one primary email can exist for a user"
    elsif !email.primary? && !email_addresses.primary.exists?
      raise "A user must have one primary email"
    end
  end

  def ensure_primary_email
    return if email_addresses.primary.exists?
    raise 'Missing primary email' if !email_addresses.exists?
    email_addresses.first.update_attribute(:primary, true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's best to have your relationships flow in one direction only. Back-links create circular dependencies that are hard to resolve.

In the first example you have a flag on one of the email addresses to indicate it's a "primary" address. You can make this more robust by defaulting to the first address if one is not explicitly flagged as primary, and where there are somehow several primary addresses, just pick the first one of those. Nothing ever works out perfectly, so having your application capable of dealing with some uncertainty instead of throwing exceptions isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Do keep in mind that your user record cannot be saved until a primary address has been designated, and it's unlikely you can associate the email address with the user address before it's been saved in the first place. This is one of those circular dependencies that can be difficult to resolve unless you're careful to save things in the correct order.

If you keep the concept of a primary address a little loose, where unless one is explicitly defined you have a reasonable default, then the amount of work you have to do is considerably less.

One thing you've discovered is that the relationships are often cached by ActiveRecord, so having two independent relationships that have overlapping data can be trouble. There's no real way to avoid this, but you can always force-reload relationships if you're concerned about stale cached data: `user.email_addresses(true)` will always fetch the records from the database.